# SQL query to find dates of last year equivalent to today's date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a SQL query to find business working dates of last year equivalent to today's date.

In this query it should fetch :-

For e.g. if today is 5th January, 2021 and it is the second day of second week of the year. So I need to find the exact equivalent date of the second day of second week of the previous year. So it would be 7th January, 2020.

And with this, I need the business working dates of that week of 7th January 2020 (i.e. excluding Saturday & Sunday)
Which will come up as 2020-Jan-06 to 2020-Jan-10 according to the example.

So I will need the report between 6th Jan - 10th Jan, 2020.

I am trying to use this code to find date of last year equivalent to today's date (5th Jan, 2021 viz. second day of second week)

`select Convert(date, (DATEADD(year, -1, getdate()+2))) ;`

Comment: Please explain how 2021-01-05 is "the second day of second week of the year".

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff, according to the business scenario, the week will start from Monday and so 5th Jan, 2021 will be second day of the second week of the year.

Comment: Your previous question has suggestions for a calendar - use one of those. You just add whatever columns you need to know that Jan 7 2021 correlates to Jan 5 2020

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have use multiple `CTE` to show you the step by step calculation. It should be pretty easy to follow.

Basically it find the `week_no` and `day_no_of_week` for `2021-01-05` and then use that to find the same date for `2020`

```
declare @input_date     date = '2021-01-05',
        @year_offset    int  = -1;  -- previous year

with 
cte1 as
(
    select  input_date          = @input_date,
            week_no             = DATEPART(WEEK, @input_date),
            first_day_of_week   = DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, @input_date), 0)
),
cte2 as
(
    select  *,
            day_no_of_week = DATEDIFF(DAY, first_day_of_week, @input_date) + 1
    from    cte1 
),
cte3 as
(
    select  *,
            first_day_of_the_prev_year = DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, @input_date) + @year_offset, 0)
    from    cte2
),
cte4 as
(
    select  *,
            first_day_of_week_prev_year = DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, DATEADD(WEEK, week_no - 1, first_day_of_the_prev_year)), 0)
    from    cte3
)
select  *,
        DATEADD(DAY, day_no_of_week - 1, first_day_of_week_prev_year) as the_required_date
from    cte4
```

Answer (score 1):

2021-01-05 is the 2nd day of the *first* week of 2021 according to ISO standards.

If you want the 2nd day of the first week of 2021, then it is either today's date minus 52 weeks or 53 weeks.  Based on the Wikipedia page for ISO dates:

> [53 week years are those] years in which 1 January or 31 December are Thursdays

So, we want that for the *previous* year.  Hence, I think the following should work:

```
select dateadd(week,
               (case when 'Thursday' in (datename(weekday, datefromparts(year(getdate()) - 1, 1, 1)),
                                         datename(weekday, datefromparts(year(getdate()) - 1, 12, 31))
                                       )
                    then -53 else -52
               end),
               convert(date, getdate()) 
              )
```

Note that this returns 2019-12-31, which is the correct value based on ISO standards.

Comment: Hi @Gordon many thanks for sharing the code. However, according to the requirement, I can't use the ISO standards as of now. And so the 5th Jan '21 will be second day of the second week and thus its equivalent will be 7th January 2020 .

Comment: Why calculate it twice, you could do `datepart(weekday, datefromparts(year(getdate()) - 1, 1, 1)) IN ('Thursday',`Friday`)` to cover those two cases?

Comment: @Charlieface . . . I don't think that handles leap years correctly.